# Build giving 1d returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++

Unable to build a single C++ file in Geany.

A program to show the employee details. When I clicked compile, it shows compilation successful. But when I build it, it shows this. Can't execute too.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

class employee
{
public:
  int id,age;
  char name[25];
  float salary;
  void getdata()
  {
    cout<<"\n enter employee id";
    cin>>id;
    cout<<"enter emplyee name";
    cin>>name;
    cout<<"\n enter employee age";
    cin>>age;
    cout<<"\n enter emplyee salary";
    cin>>salary;
  }
  
  void putdata()
  {
    cout<<"\n id="<<id<<"\n name="<<name<<"\n age="<<age<<"n salary="<<salary;
  }
  void main()
  {
    int i;
    employee e[2];
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
      cout<<"\n enter details of"<<i+1<<"employee";
      e[i].getdata();
    }
    cout<<"\n details of employees";
    for(i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
      e[i].putdata();
    }
    getch();
  }
};
```

Error Code:
[image: ErrorCode]

Comment: 1) Did you mean `ld`? I know nothing about anything named `1d`. 2) `void main ()` is invalid C++. 3) Please copy-paste the **entire** error message instead of trying to paraphrase parts of it.

Comment: Please add more details to your question like Error traces, Console output, etc. Refer the below-mentioned doc on how to ask a good question :- 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask